# Problems Changing a16x2lcd to 20x4 lcd

Tags: raspberry-pi

I am currently making a  pi project and want to upgrade the lcd output size from a 16x2 to a 20x4. 
However now that i have made this change I lose power to the pi when i connect the 5v supply to the new display.

Is this a faulty display or do I need to power the display separately? 
I have tried multiple usb power supplies  (2A)

Comment: A 2A power supply is way too much than needed, so if it does work fine, the problem doesn't come from that. I'd suspect the display. What happens when you say `I loose power` ?

Comment: Thanks for the reply loose power  i meen that the pi turns itself off and the power indicator led fades out.

Comment: Sounds like a short circuit somewhere...

Comment: But this question is probably more suited to http://electronics.stackexchange.com, it doesn't fit in topics here. http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic

Comment: That was my first  thought but I have meatered out every path way to look for short but none found. I think it is a bad display thanks

Comment: So top tip. Double check the wiring and then triple check do that a few times have a cup of tea check again have lunch then you spot the crossed wire. Thanks for the help but i made a boo boo.